# how to set an array objectype in php

Tags: php, arrays, class, types

I have a class where I want to set an array to have a strict type of class in php , eg.

```
class Person{
public string $name;
public array:Person $friends;
}
```

how  do I do this

Comment: https://blog.programster.org/php-creating-strict-type-arrays

Comment: i could write an answer, but this post is so much better and i couldn't find a suitable duplicate to answer your question.

Comment: TL;DR: you can't, but you can create your own implementation of an `ArrayObject` which behaves like an array. `public PersonCollection $friends`;

Comment: Depending on exactly _why_ you want this, the answer might be "you can't", "you can build it yourself with a fair amount of effort", or "you can put it in the docblock and use an IDE or command-line tool to verify it". I haven't read through all of the linked answers, but I imagine they cover most of the options between them.